# Firebase db with vuejs : default.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I'm starting a small project with `Vuejs` and `Firebase`. I am trying to upload `Name` and `Price` to Firestore. I checked their documentation and few tutorials, but I am stuck with this error.

[image]
[image]

```js
<div class="form-group">
      <v-btn v-on:click="saveData" class="btn btn-primary">Save data</v-btn>
</div>

import db from "../firebase";
export default {
  name: "products",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      aon: {
        Name: null,
        Price: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveData() {
      db.collection("Products")
        .add(this.Product)
        .then((docRef) => {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my firebase.js

```js
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const fb = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "!!!!!!!!!!!",
    authDomain: "!!!!!!!!",
    databaseURL: "!!!!!!!",
    projectId: "!!!!!!",
    storageBucket: "!!!!!!!",
    messagingSenderId: "!!!!!!!",
    appId: "!!!!!!!!!",
    measurementId: "!!!!!!!!!!!!"
});
const db = firebase.firestore();
export default firebase;
export {db,fb} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't initialized your firebase app. To do so :

```
//firebase.js

const db = firebase.initializeApp(fb)
export {db.firestore(),fb}
```

Then on your products page or component you wrote :

```
//products.vue

db.collection("Products").add(this.Product)...
```

this.Product object doesn't exist so it should be `this.aon`

```
//products.vue

db.collection("Products").add(this.aon)...
```

For more info : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) you need to use the `.set()`, `.add()`, `.update()` and `.doc()` methods like this.

> When you use `set()` to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create. For example:

```
await db.collection('cities').doc('new-city-id').set(data);
```

> to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling `add()`

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
const res = await db.collection('cities').add({
  name: 'Tokyo',
  country: 'Japan'
});

console.log('Added document with ID: ', res.id);
```

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`

```
const newCityRef = db.collection('cities').doc();

// Later...
const res = await newCityRef.set({
  // ...
});
```

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the `update()` method:

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Set the 'capital' field of the city
const res = await cityRef.update({capital: true});
```